# Inequality of Schmidt: $\int_S |x-y|^{-s} dy \leq \omega_n (n-s)^{-1} R^{n-s},$ where $|S| = e_n R^n = | B_R(x) |$ and $e_n = \frac{\omega_n}{n}$

Tags: inequality, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, decreasing-rearrangements

If $0<s<n$ and $S$ is a measurable set with $|S| < \infty$. Then
$$\int_S |x-y|^{-s} dy \leq \omega_n (n-s)^{-1} R^{n-s},$$
where $|S| = e_n R^n = | B_R(x) |$ and $e_n = \frac{\omega_n}{n}$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

1) Does this inequality have a name? My lecturer keeps refering to it as the inequality of Schmidt, however a Google search returns no results.

2) How do I prove it? Are there any references (books, lecture notes, ...) that contain the proof?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems kind of rearrangement inequality:
$$
\int_S |x-y|^{-s} dy \leq \int_{B_R(x)} |x-y|^{-s} dy =
\int_{B_R(0)} |y|^{-s} dy = \omega_n \int_0^R \rho^{-s}\rho^{n-1} d\rho =
\omega_n \frac{R^{n-s}}{n-s}.
$$
The first inequality can be proved, for example, using the Hardy-Littlewood inequality
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f g \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f^* g^*,
$$
where $f^*$ and $g^*$ are the symmetric decreasing rearrangements of $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Namely, assume w.l.o.g. $x=0$ and let $f(y) = |y|^{-s}$, $g(y) = \chi_S(y)$.
Then $f^*(y) = f(y)$ and $g^*(y) = \chi_{B_R} (y)$, hence
$$
\int_{S} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f g \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f^* g^*
= \int_{B_R} f.
$$

Comment: That enlightens the issue very much. The first inequality however does seem to require some intricated technique to prove?

Comment: The idea is simple. Assume $x=0$. Since the function $y \mapsto |y|^{-s}$ is radially decreasing, if you "transport" the mass of $S\setminus B_R(0)$ into $B_R(0)$ the integral would increase. I think that the argument can be made rigorous using a rearrangement tecnique.

Comment: Added a rearrangement argument. I'm not sure it's the simplest one.